# Logback logger in inner class

Tags: java, react-native, logging, logback, inner-classes

I have outer `public class ClassifierModule` and inner `public class ClassifierRunnable`. Logger implemented in outer class works fine. But when I try to implement it in inner class it doesn't work at all. I mean, there is no error, but logback doesn't create logs.

How to implement logger in inner class? (I've learnt so far that it should be non-ststic).

```
private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassifierModule.class);
```

Here is my code:

```
//outer class
public class ClassifierModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements BufferListener {

    public ClassifierModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        appState = ((MainApplication)reactContext.getApplicationContext());
        }     

    @Override
    public String getName() {
      return "Classifier";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void saveLog() {
       logger.info("Hello world");
    }

    //inner class        
    public class ClassifierRunnable implements Runnable {

        public ClassifierRunnable(double[][] buffer) {
            rawBuffer = buffer;
            PSD = new double[NUM_CHANNELS][nbBins];
        }

        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassifierRunnable.class);

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(isLogging) {

                int a = 11;
                int b = 24;

                logger.info(a)

            }
    }
}
```

My logback.xml is configured as below:

```
<configuration>
  <!-- Create a file appender for a log in the application's data directory -->
  <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/data/data/com.eeg_project/files/log/eegdata.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <!-- Write INFO (and higher-level) messages to the log file -->
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you add in your code how you actually initialize these loggers?

Comment: That goes to the class `private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NameOfTheClass.class);` and then when I want to write sth in log I use this in method: `logger.info("Hello world");`

Comment: In the code you have in the question? You call [LOG] but where do you init this [LOG]? Cannot see init in inner/outer class in your example classes?

Comment: Updated my question. There are `int a` and `int b` in inner class that I want to write in log.

Comment: Ok but there is currently not a row that logs those? Furthermore , you init `logger` but call `LOG`?

Comment: `log` is other function that was originally in the app. I'm trying to implement logger. And it works, but only in outer class. When I add it to inner class and try to save for example `int a` using `logger.info(a)` it doesn't work. It doesn't even create empty .log file as it creates when I call this function from outer class.

Comment: Firstly you should update code in your question to exactly what you have tried. Secondly it is unclear to me what you mean by 'implementing logger'. Do you try to log to separate files?

Comment: Ok, I updated exactly what I tried.

Comment: Where are you looking for the logs? If you're using Android, you should be using builtin Logcat, not Logback

Comment: But it works. Unfortunately only when it's in the outer class (creates .log file under directory specified in logback.xml). When it's like in the code I posted then it doesn't create .log file (I recieve no errors, like the button I press was empty)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add log level for inner classes, you need to add below configuration to the logback.xml file. it worked for me.

Since it is an inner class you need to separate it using $ sign from the parent class.

```
<logger name="packagename.ClassifierModule$ClassifierRunnable " level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</logger>
```

Hope this helps you with your configuration. thanks